# Detecting Outliers in Time Series (LS/AO/TC) using tsoutliers package in R. How to represent outliers in equation format?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, outliers

**Comments:**
Firstly I would like to say a big thank you to the [author](http://www.jalobe.com:8080/) of the new [tsoutliers](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tsoutliers/tsoutliers.pdf) package which implements [Chen and Liu's](http://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1993.10594321#.U6w4BXLkv2c) time series outlier detection which was published in the Journal of the American Statistical Association in 1993 in Open Source software $R$.

The package detects 5 different types of outliers iteratively in time series data:

1. Additive Outlier (AO)
2. Innovation Outlier (IO)
3. Level Shift (LS)
4. Temporary change (TC)
5. Seasonal Level Shift (SLS)

What is even more great is that this package implements auto.arima from forecast package so detecting outliers is seamless. Also the package produces nice plots for better understanding of the time series data.

**Below are my questions:**

I tried running few examples using this package and it worked great. Additive outliers and level shift are intuitive. However, I had 2 questions with regards to handing Temporary Change outlier and Innovational outliers which I'm unable to understand.

Temporary Change Outlier Example:

Consider the following example:

```
library(tsoutliers)
library(expsmooth)
library(fma)

outlier.chicken <- tsoutliers::tso(chicken,types = c("AO","LS","TC"),maxit.iloop=10)
outlier.chicken
plot(outlier.chicken)
```

The program rightly detects a level shift and a temporary change at the following location.

```
Outliers:
  type ind time coefhat tstat
1   LS  12 1935   37.14 3.153
2   TC  20 1943   36.38 3.350
```

Below is the plot and my questions.

- How to write the temporary change in an equation
  format ? (Level shift can be easily written as a binary variable,
  anytime before 1935/Obs 12 is 0 and any  time after 1935 and after is
  1.)

The equation for temporary change in the package manual and the article is given as :

$$ L(B) = \frac{1} {1-\delta B} $$

where $\delta$ is 0.7. I'm just strugling to translate this to the example above.

- My second question is about innovational outlier, I have never come
  across an innovational outlier in practice. any numercial example or 
  a case example would be very helpful.

[image: outliers]

**Edit:**
@Irishstat, the tsoutliers function does an excellent job in identifying outliers and suggesting an appropriate ARIMA model. Looking at the Nile dataset, see below application of auto.arima and then applying tsoutliers (with defaults which includes auto.arima):

```
auto.arima(Nile)
Series: Nile 
ARIMA(1,1,1)                    

Coefficients:
         ar1      ma1
      0.2544  -0.8741
s.e.  0.1194   0.0605

sigma^2 estimated as 19769:  log likelihood=-630.63
AIC=1267.25   AICc=1267.51   BIC=1275.04
```

After applying tsoutliers function, it identifies an LS outlier and additive outlier and recommends an ARIMA order (0,0,0).

```
nile.outliers <- tso(Nile,types = c("AO","LS","TC"))
nile.outliers
Series: Nile 
ARIMA(0,0,0) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
      intercept       LS29       AO43
      1097.7500  -242.2289  -399.5211
s.e.    22.6783    26.7793   120.8446

sigma^2 estimated as 14401:  log likelihood=-620.65
AIC=1249.29   AICc=1249.71   BIC=1259.71

Outliers:
  type ind time coefhat  tstat
1   LS  29 1899  -242.2 -9.045
2   AO  43 1913  -399.5 -3.306
```

[image]

Comment: I am glad to see that you found the package useful, thanks! BTW I have fixed a typo in the function that plots the results so that in the next release of the package the y-axis will cover the range of both the 
original and the adjusted series.

Comment: In the last version of the package, the function `tsoutliers` has been renamed as `tso` to avoid conflict with a function of the same name in package `forecast`.

Comment: @javlacalle I downloaded the latest tsoutliers package it still has tsoutliers not tso. I'm not sure when the package will be updated. I'm glad that we have different funtion names.

Comment: I rushed a little bit informing about the update. It takes some time until it is updated on CRAN. I've just seen that the latest version 0.4 can be downloaded from CRAN.

Comment: @javlacalle I found tsoutliers really difficult to install on my mac. I brew installed gsl, I tried to compile using `clang` and `gcc` and [neither](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065600/r-install-kfksds-on-mac) works. I think it is an awesome package but the installation really broke my heart.

Comment: @B.Mr.W. thanks for your interest in the package and reporting this issue. Installation from source of the required package [KFKSDS](http://cran.r-project.org/package=KFKSDS) requires having installed the development version of [GSL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/). I cannot check the installation process on a mac but will see if I should add something in the sources of `KFKSDS` to make the installation easier.

Comment: @B.Mr.W. I would recommend you trying the ideas in 
[this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24781125). You could also try editing the file KFKSDS/src/Makevars with the contents of Makevars.in available in the same directory of package [gsl](http://cran.r-project.org/package=gsl).

Comment: @javlacalle I have no problem installing either gsl pkg or gsl itself. And I change the Makevars and they still not work. I guess I will just use RStudio server on our server for now... and quietly wait for some magic from you. I will it could be in CRAN since it is such an awesome library. :)

Comment: @B.Mr.W. Thanks for trying this. I will inspect the sources of package gsl and see how they deal with the installation on a mac.

Comment: I had trouble installing the KFKSDS in Ubuntu 16.04.  I finally solved it installing `libgsl-dev` in system with `apt-get`.

Comment: Chicken. The 1973 outlier is missed.  The true model is a random walk. The flagging of a level shift at 1935 is a false positive. It gets 1 of 3 right and misses an outlier. Nile.  The true model is no model. 1877 and 1864 are missed, but the level shift 1899  and outlier at 1913 are found.  It gets 2 out of 2 right, but misses two outliers.

Comment: edit 1864=1964.

Comment: @tomreilly the model correctly flags the level shift at 1899 not 1935 and also identifies the true no arima (random walk/white noise). There is no false positive in the above model, your comment is misleading and confusing.

Comment: @forecaster, the "1935" comment is related to the chicken example and NOT the nile example.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The temporary change, TC, is a general type of outlier. The equation given in the documentation of the package and that you wrote is the equation that describes the dynamics of this type of outlier. You can generate it by means of the function `filter` as shown below. It is illuminating to display it for several values of delta. For $\delta=0$ the TC collapses in an additive 
outlier; on the other extreme, $\delta=1$, the TC is like a level shift.

```
tc <- rep(0, 50)
tc[20] <- 1
tc1 <- filter(tc, filter = 0, method = "recursive")
tc2 <- filter(tc, filter = 0.3, method = "recursive")
tc3 <- filter(tc, filter = 0.7, method = "recursive")
tc4 <- filter(tc, filter = 1, method = "recursive")
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
plot(tc1, main = "TC delta = 0")
plot(tc2, main = "TC delta = 0.3")
plot(tc3, main = "TC delta = 0.7")
plot(tc4, main = "TC delta = 1", type = "s")
```

[image: tremporary change]

In your example, you can use the function `outliers.effects` to represent the effects of the detected outliers on the observed series:

```
# unit impulse
m1 <- ts(outliers.effects(outlier.chicken$outliers, n = length(chicken), weights = FALSE))
tsp(m1) <- tsp(chicken)
# weighted by the estimated coefficients
m2 <- ts(outliers.effects(outlier.chicken$outliers, n = length(chicken), weights = TRUE))
tsp(m2) <- tsp(chicken)
```

The innovational outlier, IO, is more peculiar. Contrary to the other types of outliers considered in `tsoutliers`, the effect of the IO depends on the selected model and on the parameter estimates. This fact can be troublesome in series with many outliers. In the first iterations of the algorithm (where the effect of some of the outliers may not have been detected and adjusted) the quality of the estimates of the ARIMA model may not be good enough as to 
accurately define the IO. Moreover, as the algorithm makes progress a new ARIMA model may be selected. Thus, it is possible to detect an IO at a preliminary stage with an ARIMA model but eventually its dynamic is defined by another ARIMA model chosen in the last stage.

In [this document](https://www.bde.es/f/webbde/SES/servicio/software/tramo/slsoutlier.pdf) (1) it is shown that, in some circumstances, the influence of an IO may increase as the date of its occurrence becomes more distant into the past, which is something hard to interpret or assume.

The IO has an interesting potential since it may capture seasonal outliers. The other types of outliers considered in `tsoutliers`cannot capture seasonal patterns. Nevertheless, in some cases it may be better to search for a possible seasonal level shifts, SLS, instead of IO (as shown in the document mentioned before).

The IO has an appealing interpretation. It is sometimes understood as an additive outlier that affects the disturbance term and then propagates in the series according to the dynamic of the ARIMA model. In this sense, the IO is like an additive outlier, both of them affect a single observation but the IO is an impulse in the disturbance term while the AO is an impulse added directly to the values generated by the ARIMA model or the data generating process.
Whether outliers affect the innovations or are outside the disturbance term may be a matter of discussion.

In the previous reference you may find some examples of real data where IO are detected.

---

(1) *Seasonal outliers in time series.* Regina Kaiser and Agustín Maravall. Document 20.II.2001.

Comment: Thanks for detailed response. i really appreciate it. I  have few additional questions. Are there any advantages in using auto.arima, identify the p,d,q and then using tsoutliers using arima as the tsmethod?

Comment: also sometimes when I use IO, I get the follwoing warning message; stopped when ‘maxit’ was reached, also I sometime get the folloing warning: In locate.outliers.oloop(y = y, fit = fit, types = types, cval = cval,  :
  stopped when ‘maxit’ was reached. Is there a way to avoid the

Comment: The main advantage of using `forecast::auto.arima` along with `tsoutliers` is that everything gets automated. 
However, it is advisable to run the automatic procedures with alternative options. You may first for example look at the ACF or unit root tests and then choose an ARIMA model to be passed to `tsoutliers`. If any outliers are found for your proposed model then you can repeat again the analysis for the adjusted series. It is an iterative process. The automatic procedure provides a helpful guide but it may not necessarily give the ultimate or unique solution.

Comment: The procedure to locate outliers is iterative. For safety a limit is set on the number of allowable iterations. When you observe the warning you may try running the algorithm increasing the argument `maxit.iloop` to 5-6 and see if the results change. 
If the warning is returned with a large `maxit.iloop` (e.g. 20 or more) it may be a sign that something is not being modelled properly. Removing IO from the types of outliers to be considered may be a good option in some cases. In most cases you can ignore the warning. You can use `suppressWarnings` to avoid them.

Comment: @javlacelle You assume no outliers(pulses/Lshifts/seasonal level shifts AND no time trends)are present & the parameters of a model are constant over time.You use the AIC/BIC criterion to identify an ARIMA. You identify outliers(no time trends) which had been assumed to be non-existent.This sequence of unverified assumtions leading to a potentially misspecified ARIMA model might have consequences.How does this procedure would work with the Nile Data which correctly requires no differencing http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/63348/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_arima_sect060.htm

Comment: @IrishStat Using the default options with the Nile time series, a level shift is detected at observation 29 
and an additive outliers at observation 43. No ARIMA structure is identified, an ARIMA(0,0,0) with intercept is chosen. If the ARIMA(0,0,1) is specified (as suggested in the link that you gave) no outliers are detected.

Comment: The model (incorrect !) suggested in the reference was ARIMA(0,1,1) not ARIMA(0,0,1)

Comment: @IrishStat maybe I missed something but they say "the following stationary MA1 model (with regressors) appears to fit the data well". Anyway, I agree with you that the Nile data requires no differencing.

Comment: from the web http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/63348/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_arima_sect060.htm The following program fits an ARIMA model, ARIMA(0,1,1), similar to the structural model suggested in de Jong and Penzer (1998). This model is also suggested by the usual correlation analysis of the series.By default,the OUTLIER statementrequests detection of additive outliers and level shifts,assuming that the series follows the estimated model. /*-- ARIMA(0, 1, 1) Model --*/

Comment: @javlacalle Is there a way to replace the outlier with an interpolated value like the forecast::tsclean function ? Thanks.

Comment: @Anusha The function `tso` returns a series cleaned from the effects of the detected outliers. It is returned in an element called `yadj` (adjusted series), see the blue line in the first plot above. If you prefer to replace the detected outliers by interpolated values you can set those observations to `NA`s and apply the Kalman smoother as shown in [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104565/how-to-use-auto-arima-to-impute-missing-values).

Comment: @javlacalle Thank you for the reply. What method is used for calculating these adjusted values. Sorry if I missed it in the package manual. It may help users to decide which method to use.  If I may say so, isnt there a lot of change between actual and adjusted series ? Because of two outliers, the entire series is shifted down. Isnt only that point to be adjusted ? Is that correct way or am I missing something basic ? Thanks.

Comment: @Anusha The effect of the outliers is estimated in a model (e.g. ARIMA model) where the outliers are included as regressors. The regressors are weighted by the estimated coefficients and then removed from the original series, `yadj = y - xreg %*% xregcoefs`. In the example you see a clear change in the adjusted series because one of the outliers is a level shift. The package contains a document that complements the help files describing the types of outliers that are considered and the procedure to detect them. This document can be obtained through the help page of the package.

Comment: @javlacalle would you mind suggesting a book covering outliers for time series? (maybe a general time series book)

Comment: @mugen I don't know a textbook covering this issue thoroughly. As the approach discussed in this post is related to intervention analysis, any textbook (on Econometrics or Time Series) with a chapter about this issue would be helpful; for example, [Time Series Analysis. With Applications in R](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/probability/book/978-0-387-75958-6). For details, you should review some of the many journal articles dealing with this issue, starting for example by [Chen and Liu (1993)](http://doi.org/10.1080/01621459.1993.10594321) and the references therein.

Comment: @mugen, I would also check out [Tsay's](http://www.unc.edu/~jbhill/tsay.pdf) article. In addition, I would check classic book by [Pankratz](http://www.amazon.com/Forecasting-Dynamic-Regression-Models-Pankratz/dp/0471615285/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1422059381&sr=8-1&keywords=Alan+pankratz) which has good coverage on outliers.

Comment: Is there an equivalent package similar to `tsoutliers` in Python

Comment: @kanna There will probably be something similar.
You should search on the internet 
or make a question at a more appropriate forum for this kind of question, for example one of those mentioned [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/internet-support-for-statistics-software).

Comment: The link in this answer "this document" is broken, where can I find this reference?

Comment: @Frank I have fixed the link and added the reference.