# Intervention With Differencing

Tags: regression, time-series, intervention-analysis, dynamic-regression

When conducting an intervention analysis with time series data (aka Interrupted Time series) as discussed [here for example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108374/arima-intervention-transfer-function-how-to-visualize-the-effect) one requirement I have is to estimate the total gain (or loss) due to the intervention - i.e. number of units gained or lost (the Y variable).

Not entirely understanding how to estimate the intervention function using a filter function within R, I went about it in a brute force manner, hoping this is general enough to work in any situation.

Lets say that given the data

```
 cds<- structure(c(2580L, 2263L, 3679L, 3461L, 3645L, 3716L, 3955L, 
    3362L, 2637L, 2524L, 2084L, 2031L, 2256L, 2401L, 3253L, 2881L, 
    2555L, 2585L, 3015L, 2608L, 3676L, 5763L, 4626L, 3848L, 4523L, 
    4186L, 4070L, 4000L, 3498L), .Dim = c(29L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
        NULL, "CD"), .Tsp = c(2012, 2014.33333333333, 12), class = "ts")
```

we decide that the best fitting model is as follows, with the intervention function as

$m_t= \frac{\omega_0}{(1-\delta B)}X_t$ where $X_t$ is a pulse at October 2013.

```
fit4 <- arimax(log(cds), order = c(1,1,0),include.mean=FALSE, 
               xtransf = data.frame(Oct13 = 1*(seq_along(cds)==22)),
               transfer = list(c(1,0))
               ,xreg=1*(seq_along(cds)==3))
fit4

#    ARIMA(1,1,0)                    

#    Coefficients:
#              ar1    xreg  Oct13-AR1  Oct13-MA0
#          -0.0184  0.2718     0.4295     0.4392
#    s.e.   0.2124  0.1072     0.3589     0.1485

#    sigma^2 estimated as 0.02176:  log likelihood=13.85
#    AIC=-19.71   AICc=-16.98   BIC=-13.05
```

I have two questions:

1) Even though we have differenced the ARIMA errors , to assess the intervention function which was then technically fit using the differenced series $\bigtriangledown X_t $ is there anything we need to do in order to "change back" the estimate of $\omega_0$ or $\delta$ from using $\bigtriangledown X_t $ to $ X_t $?

2) Is this correct: In order to determine the gain of the intervention, I constructed the intervention $m_t$ from the parameters. Once I have $m_t$ then I compare the fitted values from the model fit4 (exp() to reverse the log) to exp( fitted values minus $m_t$ ) and determine that over the observed period, the intervention resulted in  3342.37 extra units.

**Is this process the correct one to determine the gain generally from an intervention analysis?**

```
    int_vect1<-1*(seq_along(cds)==22)
    wo<- 0.4392
    delta<-0.4295


    mt<-rep(0,length(int_vect1))

    for (i in 1:length(int_vect1))
    {

      if (i>1)
      {
        mt[i]<-wo*int_vect1[i]+delta*mt[i-1]
      }

    }


    mt

sum(exp(fitted(fit4)) - (exp(fitted(fit4) - mt)))
```

Comment: Wondering if anyone can shed light on the proper way to estimate the impact of an intervention - generally, if the procedure I demonstrated is in fact correct?

Comment: This is a great question. I suspect that the choice of indicator function might not be the best choice depending on the nature of the intervention. Perhaps an exponential decay function, $m_t = \exp(\alpha(t - i)) \text{if} i \ge t \text{else} 0$ for some scaling parameter $\alpha$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this is toy example:

To answer your first question:

1) Even though we have differenced the ARIMA errors , to assess the intervention function which was then technically fit using the differenced series ▽Xt is there anything we need to do in order to "change back" the estimate of ω0 or δ from using ▽Xt to Xt?

When you difference the data, you **should** difference the response/intervention variables. When you back difference (transform) after you model then this would  automatically take care  of differencing** I know this is very easy when you use `SAS Proc ARIMA`. I dont know how to do this `R`.

Second Question:

2) Is this correct: In order to determine the gain of the intervention, I constructed the intervention mt from the parameters. Once I have mt then I compare the fitted values from the model fit4 (exp() to reverse the log) to exp( fitted values minus mt ) and determine that over the observed period, the intervention resulted in 3342.37 extra units.

To determine, gain in intervention, you need to take exponent and then subtract -1, this would give the proportion or incremental effect. To demonstrate this in your case, see below. For the first month, the impact was 55% of original sales and rapidly decays. Cumulativelt you have 4580 units of incremental effect (Oct 13  thru Feb 2014. (I referred to [Forecasting Principle and Applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0075611201) by Delurgio P: 518. There is an excellent voluminous chapter on intervention analysis).

Someone please correct if this methodology is correct ?

Pulse intervention + decay is clearly not sufficient in this case, I would do a pulse + permanent level shift as shown in the diagram (e) below which is from the classic paper by [Box and Tiao](http://rmgsc.cr.usgs.gov/outgoing/threshold_articles/Box_Tiao1975.pdf).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @forecaster. How did you get 3170 as the effect? Here is what I did, I looked at the fitted values of the model, which was 8.64245833 (still on the log scale). Then, exp(8.64245833) = 5667.244674. Then, I took 8.64245833 - 0.4392 = 8.20325833. Since exp(8.64245833) - exp(8.20325833) = 2014.411599 this is the effect. exp(8.64245833)/ exp(8.20325833) = 1.55 which looked to me like support for this.

Comment: You used the actuals and the modeled effect I guess, versus my approach which used the model for both. I used the idea of what does the model say with and without the effect. Which is right?

Comment: Hi @B_miner, with logarithmic transformation scale we need to look at rate of change. The approach I outlined is direct approach per the textbook, I quoted. However, your approach is reasonable as well. I'll screenshot the textbook pages in the near future.

Comment: The rate of change was 0.55 which is also the rate of change in the model approach I took. I wonder which approach is more right? I lean towards mine since the approach is based on the model (fitted veruss actuals). If the model is very close to actual, the two approaches will be the sample. I would like to see the pages. I see the book looks out of print?

Comment: yes, the book is out of print. The book example is a permanent change vs. pulse intervention in your example. I think your approach is straight forward and accurate.

Comment: Has your reading lead you to believe that regardless of how you difference the model (including seasonal), the coefficients from arimax for the intervention are on the scale of the original data and hence you can use them directly in the transfer function formula for the intervention to get the effect? I cant find anywhere that states this but it seems to be the case from examples I found.

Comment: @B_Miner, differencing simply removes spurious corelation, and will not impact the coefficients.

Comment: It seems like that is true for intervention variables....from a couple examples (including from the Pankratz book you once recommended - which is great!) I have seen. But then there are other accounts, including a recent question I posted that IrishStat responded to, that seems the interpretation should be different with differencing. Confusing.

Answer (score 0):

@forecaster  After allowing AUTOBOX to identify 3 outliers using 29 values (not inappropriate in y experience) a useful model was found [image] and here [image] . The residual acf plot does not suggest an under-specified model[image] . The Actual/Fit/Forecast plot is [image] with Fit/Forecast here [image] . Forecaster had (correctly) previously mentioned how a pulse variable can morph into a level/step variable when a denominator coefficient of nearly 1.0 is introduced. In finding two level shifts (the most recent one starting in 9/2013) and a pulse at 10/2013 , the model presents a clearer picture. In terms of the impact of the pulse at 10/13 it is simply the value of the coefficient. HTH

Comment: Which of the two questions were you answering?

Comment: The first question premised a model that assumed a log transform which I believe is not warranted. The pulse at 10/2013 = 1710 which is the estimate of the effect at 10/2013

Comment: @B_Miner you could say the level shift at 9/2013 raised things by 1480 thus the net lift at 10/2013 would be 1710+1480=3190

Comment: This post seems to be more of an extended comment on the question than it is an answer to any part of the question. Perhaps it could be augmented to address the questions directly?

Comment: The false premise of the first question is the crux of my answer : taking logs and incorporating unnecessary differencing is questionable/incorrect in my opinion ... thus my "answer" is  in part to correct the premise and to suggest the effect of the impact at 10/2013 is simply the sum of a temporary and permanent change. Even though the OP has accepted another answer I haven't.

Comment: @Irsihstat, the real question is **NOT** about differencing and transforming, it is about **HOW** to handle the aforementioned in the context of transfer function models. The example provided in the OP is simply a toy example to help formulate the question. There are many instances where I had to take both differencing and tranformation in transfer function models.