# Identifying pattern in timeseries using Mean

Tags: machine-learning, time-series

I have time series data which has 5 days worth of data. The pattern of the is mostly stable (assuming period is a day).

For example, values will be above 50 for certain hours (active) during the last 24 hours continuously and below 50 for remaining hours (cool down).

The approach I am using to find out the hours of this pattern is calculate the "mean" of the data and if the real value is below the mean which means (possible cool down hours). Is this good approach to classify this pattern or any other suggestions in statistical algorithms? Please advise.

Here is sample data.

[image]

Time series data:

```
42.27,4.61,28.01,26.53,24.16,40.81,12.94,41.78,33.82,1.30,37.57,14.24,2.12,41.39,46.73,45.08,31.81,46.86,21.51,5.16,1.36,15.61,34.10,17.91,5.65,8.82,41.88,30.12,12.33,46.79,43.80,30.95,17.89,31.30,37.11,10.72,17.38,20.23,1.96,25.14,40.56,36.26,20.73,9.54,27.36,43.94,12.93,10.58,12.12,10.08,49.32,35.99,27.38,6.95,43.64,23.38,35.15,14.67,45.84,6.22,89.10,75.42,75.91,76.59,76.82,94.63,95.48,72.13,74.41,97.00,91.11,95.39,73.87,74.17,91.81,92.06,83.36,98.26,80.74,87.64,84.13,70.93,94.49,74.08,95.82,75.36,75.72,77.66,83.76,70.92,83.83,96.81,76.12,80.65,84.19,76.53,70.36,72.11,85.32,88.26,75.39,71.26,37.74,36.15,50.00,21.64,46.87,14.93,38.30,25.01,11.95,20.76,9.59,10.84,10.81,37.91,13.22,34.63,45.33,16.83,40.60,2.36,23.38,35.90,11.45,47.73,21.32,46.96,12.25,14.49,38.71,40.25,23.85,29.98,12.58,48.62,30.12,5.65,4.05,23.39,16.58,26.19,37.78,3.71,2.22,40.45,42.80,45.11,26.09,38.63,21.38,8.24,1.98,45.49,29.21,38.10,42.24,26.06,21.78,13.48,6.89,34.78,9.59,34.93,22.42,1.04,5.41,3.02,14.89,39.50,25.93,19.20,6.32,6.89,13.63,6.79,2.84,8.12,45.05,34.22,33.09,33.77,31.46,29.78,17.43,42.21,32.87,45.60,3.22,26.44,32.51,28.90,7.39,8.65,7.24,44.75,10.25,43.37,1.79,28.18,12.75,40.54,19.42,12.54,93.55,89.39,84.66,79.53,79.11,81.44,73.84,83.25,77.61,70.11,94.38,99.22,92.08,75.82,83.72,77.27,99.36,87.34,89.42,81.37,90.87,79.51,86.96,83.26,94.64,88.51,83.24,86.86,92.31,76.89,72.59,76.69,83.45,93.10,89.86,85.57,80.29,90.37,78.70,91.45,78.27,93.84,29.01,10.86,18.97,39.04,28.52,2.36,41.53,41.88,9.89,4.29,46.48,38.99,10.35,43.59,10.41,35.25,19.65,17.26,48.39,36.02,11.03,19.13,47.12,2.82,48.11,6.05,45.47,32.36,36.25,17.88,11.02,31.28,36.93,18.23,30.72,7.32,42.38,49.36,1.40,10.85,9.09,34.55,13.77,2.13,42.64,27.46,37.40,44.58,16.03,36.16,1.24,9.32,1.16,7.50,23.53,20.96,36.51,22.07,48.87,30.00,21.99,49.20,43.00,9.33,4.35,23.14,37.11,5.16,9.37,39.44,45.15,30.33,49.42,29.65,38.75,1.84,9.73,1.14,8.77,25.75,17.49,12.33,19.38,6.41,12.05,10.95,27.95,31.92,45.75,8.74,28.59,29.71,49.35,35.20,27.04,31.45,33.90,3.75,17.06,40.80,15.40,40.08,92.62,82.40,96.59,100.00,70.30,87.23,98.25,81.96,78.42,70.73,94.68,81.59,74.53,90.63,83.22,86.40,88.55,85.52,75.91,97.27,89.51,77.01,98.74,72.67,84.00,94.95,98.63,96.02,80.49,84.78,94.82,89.32,84.14,71.47,94.94,94.17,95.28,97.12,74.31,92.81,75.19,92.66,10.29,33.07,37.32,32.12,9.95,9.10,14.50,42.61,14.12,22.63,44.54,40.73,2.83,5.88,23.63,2.03,42.87,21.15,32.60,39.01,23.28,31.06,45.87,4.71,37.43,34.40,47.96,42.43,35.33,4.13,21.23,19.82,49.10,14.17,33.00,36.12,6.54,39.17,17.24,49.64,47.67,35.31,24.02,43.88,28.74,44.48,12.30,24.97,10.40,27.44,46.99,43.66,44.30,32.11,39.79,20.05,10.72,33.89,2.18,44.80,43.44,46.92,27.07,28.46,44.10,44.69,44.88,41.90,43.08,35.41,8.24,18.53,8.08,19.58,42.60,11.43,8.67,43.00,17.34,39.09,25.37,9.06,15.26,6.48,48.13,11.26,49.17,43.29,45.06,5.52,12.80,12.99,42.11,32.25,20.92,38.24,36.19,27.67,44.88,39.87,49.22,43.09,90.94,81.38,70.57,82.90,92.11,91.72,90.26,79.71,77.16,77.91,90.57,94.32,75.41,75.05,89.26,97.06,83.79,74.84,78.24,91.21,99.92,83.61,82.25,92.79,79.66,98.50,76.80,89.41,80.75,96.31,83.42,74.05,77.17,86.55,96.43,73.81,92.98,76.85,81.40,76.21,92.98,88.07,38.44,14.88,11.73,43.47,31.29,25.70,23.49,2.48,19.28,36.79,45.36,7.60,4.53,32.79,10.05,47.17,31.25,49.18,28.43,6.33,45.16,13.71,36.72,2.60,36.87,19.97,6.70,26.64,27.90,36.21,11.41,38.43,1.48,12.28,16.49,27.86,19.41,47.46,34.63,22.81,39.27,2.54,27.95,31.98,27.28,41.13,15.64,9.48,18.01,48.18,1.01,37.43,41.67,29.45,10.51,49.52,2.77,11.69,32.74,38.57,4.48,7.18,9.52,4.89,13.36,37.63,21.08,14.36,15.21,6.41,32.78,14.73,11.89,6.14,33.00,8.47,4.46,24.84,8.86,47.25,45.56,32.04,15.90,13.23,25.66,10.88,24.74,8.86,27.80,33.60,39.53,14.37,39.66,10.13,28.92,46.49,23.37,24.52,28.07,6.03,9.18,14.65,82.32,96.54,82.14,78.37,89.62,81.25,93.34,99.62,75.92,77.14,78.34,96.73,88.59,79.90,97.49,74.45,70.74,98.21,87.60,91.79,91.95,74.48,99.02,73.25,78.19,97.15,89.70,89.03,88.57,95.11,94.49,90.67,85.31,74.17,71.67,94.14,81.31,72.67,89.21,85.90,70.74,95.34,39.17,36.94,49.62,20.66,12.38,8.01,3.83,31.49,25.25,25.15,19.88,27.19,29.26,48.74,43.39,22.72,37.97,4.06,19.60,30.26,48.45,40.41,21.26,20.93,3.34,45.40,11.25,16.10,15.72,28.82,44.78,13.26,3.81,48.81,2.11,30.07,4.06,31.66,13.78,46.63,22.74,25.13
```

Answer (score 2):

Your approach to time series analysis is quite arbitrary and will not yield the kind information that will help you characterize or understand the nature of the data. The mean is a descriptive statistic not necessarily an inferential statistic.

In general the concept of UCM should be of interest to you. Unobserved Components Models propose that the data be decomposed into trend,level shifts , seasonal structure and any and all idiosyncratic components that are identifiable. The task is clear ... "What does the data tell us? "  , "What are the underlying systematic patterns ? if any !" ,  " Is it memory driven ? " , "Are there points in time that are driven by unspecified but consistent exogenous activity ?" . "Should we be combining memory an unspecified but important predictor variables ?"

I took your 720 values and used a program called AUTOBOX which integrates the UCM approach while dealing with anomalies and Gaussian Violations which are waiting to  be discovered. I have helped to develop this program and report this for transparency reasons.

Two early researchers focused on the idea on Exploratory Data Analysis (EDA) a term coined by John Tukey who worked primarily in cross-sectional data AND George Box (the BOX of AUTOBOX) while dealing with time series data. Both pioneered an iterative approach to model identification or as you suggested "classify the pattern".

Your 720 values yielded the following (possibly) useful model containing an arima component (0,1,0) and three seasonal dummies while identifying a few data points that were anomalies. [image] Hours 6, 12,and 23 were identified as systematically usual i.e. they reflected exogenous input 
without assigning cause. The plot contains a 144 period out forecast )(1 day ).

The three "seasonal dummy" series were found using Intervention Detection procedures which are available through many software packages and are base upon material discussed
http://docplayer.net/12080848-Outliers-level-shifts-and-variance-changes-in-time-series.html and for an R implementation see [Intervention Analysis Coding in R TSA Package](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108111/intervention-analysis-coding-in-r-tsa-package?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The Actual & Fit presentation is here [image] with residual plot here [image]

The Interventions (Pulses) that were identified point to data points that were exceptional possibly  reflecting an unspecified causal series.

[image]

The augmented data matrix detailing the nature of the empirically developed "dummy" predictors is here [image]

If your real question is primarily "how do I classify the pattern " then this answer should suffice.

Arithmetic suggested 5 days ( you presented 720 values ) not 4 as you had mentioned thus 144 values per day with 6 readings per hour . Is that correct ?

What this Exploratory Data Analysis" suggest is that each and every 6th , 12th and 23rd hour or through memory the 7th, 13th and 24th values  ...something outside factor is impacting the data ... Does the OP know what this might be ? If not it might be time to find out and use that knowledge to replace the three dummy indicators.

Now we can use the equation to predict. Following is a monte-carlo simulation for the next hour for the next day [image] . One can then use this probability distribution to assess whether or not the next observation (period 721 ; day 6 hour 1) deviates significantly from expectations triggering a conclusion that we are at the 
"higher level"

Thus we are not comparing the next reading to the mean BUT to an expectation .

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, it is 5 days worth of data, updated the question.

Comment: I spent sometime digesting your answer. May be I didn't word my question clearly, what I am trying to do here is not "predict" or "forecast" for future. I need to be able to identify/describe that every day in the given series 10 to 5 is "busy"  and remaining time is "cool down" period. To get that 10 to 5 window, don't I need to use one of the statistics (AVG or MEDIAN or STD DEV or combination of these) as basis (In my code/program, not through manual exploration)? please advise.

Comment: perhaps we could do a chat session and I will try and help u

Comment: Yes, happy to do that. What time and how can we initiate the session?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100554/discussion-between-irishstat-and-kosa).