# Fit mixture of distributions to your time-series data in R

Tags: r, time-series, normal-distribution, clustering, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I have time-series data containing 1440 observations and the plot of the data is
[image]

I want to fit the Gaussian Mixture Models (GMM) to the above plot, and for the same I am using Mclust function of [mclust](https://cran.fhcrc.org/web/packages/mclust/index.html) package. Finally, I want a fit somewhat like this:
[image]

On using Mclust function, I do get following statistics

```
   mclus_data <- Mclust(givendataseries)
   > summary(mclus_data)
----------------------------------------------------
Gaussian finite mixture model fitted by EM algorithm 
----------------------------------------------------

Mclust E (univariate, equal variance) model with 8 components:

 log.likelihood    n df      BIC      ICL
       9525.438 1440 16 18934.52 18183.67

Clustering table:
   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8 
1262    0    0    0    0   13  114   51
```

In the above statistic, I can not understand following:

1. Significance of `log.likelihood`, `BIC` and `ICL`. I can understand what each of them is, but what their magnitude/value refers to?
2. It shows there are 8 clusters, but why cluster no. `2,3,4,5` has `0` values? What does this mean?
3. From the plot it is clear that there must be two Guassians, but why `Mclust` function shows there are 8 Guassians?

**Update:**
Actually, I want to do model based clustering of time series data. But currently  I want to fit the distribution to my raw data, as shown in Figure 1 on page no. 3 of [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q50e9q168lt27si/VerstileClusteringMethod.pdf?dl=0) paper. For your quick reference, mentioned figure in said paper is
[image]

Comment: Obviously, this data is not Gaussian at all.

Comment: Furthermore, the method is not doing what you think it does: it **does not know time**. It does *not* try to fit a line to your series.

Comment: Ok. But clearly there are two peaks in the original plot. Can't I fit Guassians around these two peaks. Mainly I am concerned how to fit a distribution to the original given time series data.

Comment: There are about *twenty* peaks. There is a dominant alternate level. There is no Gaussian distribution here (not even the bell-shaped curve you get when integraring over Gaussian data). You need to understand this difference, or you will be on the wrong track.

Comment: What is your actual objective? You've described a step you think will help you towards this objective, but have been told that this step is not appropriate. Better approaches can only be suggested if you describe the objective.

Comment: Also if you want to include information about time, this data is *not* univariate because you have actual values and time - it is bivariate! If you want to treat it as univariate then ignore the time.

Comment: @Roland:I have added objective as an update to the question at the end.

Comment: @Tim, I already had doubt about this, but while using `Mclust` function and displaying summary as shown in main question, I got clear that mclust package considers input data as univaraite. Time is just used for indexing purpose.

Comment: If you want to ignore the time than the plots you provided are totally irrelevant to your problem and the univariate methods won't give you the result as illustrated by your second plot...

Comment: @Tim, I do not want to lose the time component. It is always there. The above plots correspond to `1440` minutes of a day.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse, Thanks for the clarifications. I have improved my question with an update section. Can you provide me some further guidance - how can I achieve the plot placed at the bottom of quesion?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a misunderstanding in your question that needs a correction. Time-series model is *not* univariate since you have two variables: actual values and time. To provide an example let's take a time-series data, say `woolyrnq` data from `forecast` R library (plotted below).

[image]

Now, if you use univariate Mclust to find clusters it will *ignore* the time component and find two clusters.

```
----------------------------------------------------
Gaussian finite mixture model fitted by EM algorithm 
----------------------------------------------------

Mclust V (univariate, unequal variance) model with 2 components:

 log.likelihood   n df     BIC       ICL
      -984.6021 119  5 -1993.1 -2002.634

Clustering table:
 1  2 
84 35
```

We can also plot the density of fitted clusters:

[image]

If you look at the x-axis of this plot, you'll learn that it is related to *values* of your data (y-axis on the first plot), *not* to time. Now, if we color the point-values of the time series by cluster assignments, it will be more clear:

[image]

The method discovered clusters of "high" and "low" values, *independent of time*. The same applies to the eight clusters discovered by Mclust with your data - they ignore the time, so are unrelated to the peaks marked by you on the second plot in your question.

If you want to use Mclust for such data, you need to use a *bivariate* model including time. For example, with the `woolyrnq` data you can obtain two such clusters

```
fit2 <- Mclust(data.frame(x = woolyrnq, y = time(woolyrnq)))
plot(x, col = fit2$classification)
```

[image]

Or illustrated as 2-dimmensional density plot:

[image]

As you can see, now the clusters relate to the "higher" wool production in Australia up to the early 1970' and "lower" production afterwards. Notice that this is a bivariate, rather than univariate, model. The plot from the paper that you refer to is a marginalized version of such multidimensional density plot and can be easily obtained by extracting `mean` and `variance` objects from `parameters` in `Mclust` object (example below).

```
# densities are multiplied by arbitrary constants to fit the y-axis
curve(dnorm(x, fit2$parameters$mean[2, 2], fit2$parameters$variance$sigma[2,2,2])*1e5, add = F, col="green", from = 1965, to = 1995, ylim = c(2000, 8000), xlab = "time", ylab = "woolyrnq")
curve(dnorm(x, fit2$parameters$mean[2, 1], fit2$parameters$variance$sigma[2,2,1])*5e5, add = T, col="red", from = 1965, to = 1995)
lines(as.numeric(time(woolyrnq)), as.numeric(woolyrnq))
```

[image]

The plot above, if expanded a little bit, could be also a very good example of why using such method is not really the best way to go with time series, what would get obvious if you look at the plot below.

[image]

As you can see, if you made predictions from such mixture model, you'll conclude that there were literally no wool production in Australia before 1850 and there would be no such production in ninety years from now. Time series are not really Gaussian shaped, so such methods should be used with caution.

---

R note: In the example provided `ts` object was used, where information about time units was available by the `time` method. However if you are not using a `ts` object, than you have to use additional variable that describes the time with appropriate time units.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I undertstood it. From the last two days, I am trying to get the mentioned plot, but with no luck. In the referenced paper, authors have used the `mclust` package to get such plots. You can see referenced paper plots

Comment: Yes, I got it. But, I want to fit the distributions as shown in updated (plot at the bottom) question.

Comment: Still working on to get above plot from density plot obtained via `Mclust` function, having said that the plot is marginalized version of multidimensional density plot.

Comment: @HaroonRashid "how to make a plot in R" is an off-topic kind of questions in here, but if it helps you anyhow I updated the answer with sample code to produce the plot (for more complicated problems you would have to read the documentation and make some changes in it to work).