# Clustering methods that take data order into account

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, clustering, data-mining

Is there any clustering methods that allows to take the time information (i.e. data order) into account ? That is, in addition to maximising intra-cluster similarity and minimising inter-cluster similarity, one could also maximise the "average time spent within a cluster" (or minimise "frequency of cluster changes"). I don't know how to do that since time (or data order) is not a spacial dimension.

As an a simple illustrative example, if we consider two clusters and we have three equally distant data points, then the two clusters may look differently depending on the order:

AAAAAABCBACBCCBBCB ===> We might want to group points A in the same cluster and points B,C in the other cluster

ABABABABAABCCCACCCCC ==> We might want to group points A,B in the same cluster and points C in the other cluster

Comment: You can use time as one of the variables taken into consideration in clustering, see this example: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/182232/fit-mixture-of-distributions-to-your-time-series-data-in-r/182354#182354 (it also discusses possible pitfails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time-based clustering methods are beginning to get the attention they deserve. They can be distinguished based on whether or not they are moment-based vs non-moment based. Here are a few references:

**Moment methods based on global statistics:**
   Rob Hyndman's paper *Dimension Reduction for Clustering Time Series Using Global Characteristics* available here: http://www.robjhyndman.com/papers/wang2.pdf

Moment methods based on hidden markov models:
   Steve Scott's papers, e.g., *Hidden Markov Models for Longitudinal Comparisons* available here: https://sites.google.com/site/stevethebayesian/googlepageforstevenlscott/home

Oded Netzer's paper *A Hidden Markov Model of Customer Relationship Dynamics* available here: https://www0.gsb.columbia.edu/mygsb/faculty/research/pubfiles/2618/HMM%20of%20Customer%20Relationship%20Dynamics.pdf

**Non-moment based methods**, which are typically rooted in complexity and information theory:

Andreas Brandmaier's permutation distribution clustering, as well as his R modules, *pdc: An R Package for Complexity-Based Clustering of Time Series* available here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pdc/pdc.pdf

**For an excellent overview** of time series clustering that is now a few years old see Aggarwal and Reddy's book *Data Clustering* 
[http://www.amazon.com/Data-Clustering-Algorithms-Applications-Knowledge/dp/1466558210/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1457449361&sr=8-1&keywords=reddy+data+clustering](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1466558210)

Answer (score -1):

You can use dynamic time wrapping distance function with hierarchical clustering algorithm. Here are some links:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering