# Using ARIMA with exogenous regressors for outlier detection in R

Tags: time-series, arima, outliers, anomaly-detection

I would like to detect outliers in real-time data that is aggregated per hour. For this example, I've selected the hourly pedestrian data from Melbourne, Australia
([Pedestrian volume (updated monthly)](https://data.melbourne.vic.gov.au/Transport-Movement/Pedestrian-volume-updated-monthly-/b2ak-trbp), [Pedestrian Counting System](http://www.pedestrian.melbourne.vic.gov.au/))

[I understand there are a large number of existing detection algorithms](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104882/detecting-outliers-in-time-series-ls-ao-tc-using-tsoutliers-package-in-r-how), which in time I'll learn and use.
In the short term I'd like to use the simplest approach. One such method is outlined by @Aksakal in the following stackexchange post:

[What algorithm should I use to detect anomalies on time-series?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152644/what-algorithm-should-i-use-to-detect-anomalies-on-time-series)

> I think the key is "unexpected" qualifier in your graph. In order to
>   detect the *unexpected* you need to have an idea of what's *expected*.
>
> I would start with a simple time series model such as AR(p) or
>   ARMA(p,q). Fit it to data, add seasonality as appropriate. For
>   instance, your SAR(1)(24) model could be: $y_{t}=c+\phi  y_{t-1}+\Phi_{24}y_{t-24}+\Phi_{25}y_{t-25}+\varepsilon_t$, where $t$
>   is time in hours. So, you'd be predicting the graph for the next hour.
>   Whenever the prediction error $e_t=y_t-\hat y_t$ is "too big" you
>   throw an alert.
>
> When you estimate the model you'll get the variance
>   $\sigma_\varepsilon$ of the error $\varepsilon_t$. Depending on your
>   distributional assumptions, such as normal, you can set the threshold
>   based on the probability, such as $|e_t|<3\sigma_\varepsilon$ for
>   99.7% or one-sided $e_t>3\sigma_\varepsilon$.
>
> The number of visitors is probably quite persistent, but super
>   seasonal. It might work better to try seasonal dummies instead of the
>   multiplicative seasonality, then you'd try ARMAX where X stands for
>   exogenous variables, which could be anything like holiday dummy, hour
>   dummies, weekend dummies etc.

Unfortunately the original post does not go into details, hence my question:

*How is the variance $\sigma_\varepsilon$ of the ARIMA error term ($\varepsilon_t$) calculated for the case outlined above?*

I could not find any good references on detailing this process. [Penn Stat](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/node/72/) provides a good overview of using Linear Regression Models with Autoregressive Errors, but does not seem to cover this area.

Any guidance would be appreciated.