# Using Kalman filters to impute Missing Values in Time Series

Tags: data-imputation, kalman-filter

I am interested in how Kalman Filters can be used to impute missing values in Time Series Data. Is it also applicable if some consecutive time points are missing? I cannot find much on this topic. Any explanations, comments and links are welcome and appreciated!

Comment: You may be interested in [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104565/how-to-use-auto-arima-to-impute-missing-values/104606#104606). It gives an example based on the state-space representation of an ARIMA model to impute missing values by means of the Kalman filter.

Comment: @javlacalle thanks, I already knew this post and it is a great example for a concrete implementation. But I am rather interested in the theoretical background.

Comment: I suggest you this simply python implementation https://stackoverflow.com/a/63630858/10375049

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Preliminaries: Kalman filtering**:

Kalman filters operate on state-space models of the form (there are several ways to write it; this is an easy one based on [Durbin and Koopman (2012)](http://www.ssfpack.com/DKbook.html); all of the following is based on that book, which is excellent):

$$
\begin{align}
y_t & = Z \alpha_t + \varepsilon_t \qquad & \varepsilon_t \sim N(0, H) \\
\alpha_{t_1} & = T \alpha_t + \eta_t & \eta_t \sim N(0, Q) \\
\alpha_1 & \sim N(a_1, P_1)
\end{align}
$$

where $y_t$ is the observed series (possibly with missing values) but $\alpha_t$ is fully unobserved. The first equation (the "measurement" equation) says that the observed data is related to the unobserved states in a particular way. The second equation (the "transition" equation) says that the unobserved states evolve over time in a particular way.

The Kalman filter operates to find optimal estimates of $\alpha_t$ ($\alpha_t$ is assumed to be Normal: $\alpha_t \sim N(a_t, P_t)$, so what the Kalman filter actually does is to compute the conditional mean and variance of the distribution for $\alpha_t$ conditional on observations up to time $t$).

In the typical case (when observations are available) the Kalman filter uses the estimate of the current state and the current observation $y_t$ to do the best it can to estimate the next state $\alpha_{t+1}$, as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
a_{t+1} & = T a_t + K_t (y_t - Z \alpha_t) \\
P_{t+1} & = T P_t (T - K_t Z)' + Q
\end{align}
$$

where $K_t$ is the "Kalman gain".

When there is not an observation, the Kalman filter still wants to compute $a_{t+1}$ and $P_{t+1}$ in the best possible way. Since $y_t$ is unavailable, it cannot make use of the measurement equation, but *it can still use the transition equation*. Thus, when $y_t$ is missing, the Kalman filter instead computes:

$$
\begin{align}
a_{t+1} & = T a_t \\
P_{t+1} & = T P_t T' + Q
\end{align}
$$

Essentially, it says that given $\alpha_t$, my best guess as to $\alpha_{t+1}$ without data is just the evolution specified in the transition equation. This can be performed for any number of time periods with missing data.

If there *is* data $y_t$, then the first set of filtering equations take the best guess without data, and add a "correction" in, based on how good the previous estimate was.

---

**Imputing data**:

Once the Kalman filter has been applied to the entire time range, you have optimal estimates of the states $a_t, P_t$ for $t = 1, 2, \dots, T$. Imputing data is then simple via the measurement equation. In particular, you just calculate:

$$\hat y_t = Z a_t $$

---

As for a reference, Durbin and Koopman (2012) is excellent; section 4.10 discusses missing observations.

- Durbin, J., & Koopman, S. J. (2012). Time series analysis by state
  space methods (No. 38). Oxford University Press.

Comment: Using the smoother solution would make more sense for imputing  (since one already has all (non-missing) data, why not use the information in the future values, too)

Answer (score 0):

The example in the [posting that javlacalle points to](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104565/how-to-use-auto-arima-to-impute-missing-values/104606#104606) in their comment features consecutive missing time points. You might also be interested in intervals around the imputed (in-sample forecasted) values, the calculation of which appears in this [State Space paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v41/i04/paper), in section 2.1.

Another paper that might be interesting is [this one](http://blog.zhaw.ch/idp/sefblog/uploads/state_space_script.pdf).