# Polynomial regression for missing value imputation

Tags: time-series, missing-data, data-imputation

I am trying to impute missing values by fitting higher degree polynomial.

I have highly autocorralated time series meaning each value at t must be close to t-1. There are some noise and missing values that im trying to fix. I am not sure how to classify sequences of missing data and how long sequences before and after the gap(sequence of missing values) used for fitting must be. [image]

In the picture you can see the gap of missing values which obviously can be recovered by using 3-4th degree polinomial by fitting it on some values before and after the gap. Is there any familiar approach to this?

Comment: You may be interested in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104565/how-to-use-auto-arima-to-impute-missing-values/).

Comment: @javlacalle thanks for the interesting reference, although I managed to impute missing values by using Cubic Splines and do the job perfectly!

Comment: If you want an interpolation technique which includes some measure of uncertainty, consider Kriging (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriging), aka Gaussian Process. Though, if the gaps are really as small as shown on your images, I think simply taking the mean between the two end-points would be fine as well (linear interpolation).

Answer (score 0):

I tried this approach and I think is very useful for filling the gaps in missing data of a numeric variable. The same approach can be used to have some control over numeric data noise (i.e by fitting a suitable polynomial degree to noisy data) where the model can then be used to generate a cleaner data for the same feature.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "this approach"?  The OP describes two different methods: the one in the question and a different one in a comment.  Either one requires more details concerning the selection of local data used to perform the imputation across each gap.